# Errors with vector and struct

Tags: c++, vector, struct

So I decided to try and make the program I was writing in my previous question only using the vector class and I am still getting errors.

The Errors:

```
error: 'match' does not name a type
error: 'match' was not declared in the scope
error: 'conversion from 'int' to non-scalar type 'WordInfo' requested
```

My Code:

```
 #include <cstdlib>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <algorithm>


    using namespace std;

    struct WordInfo {
        string text;
        int count;
    };

    int main(int argc, char** argv) {

        enum {
            total, unique, individual
        } mode = total;
        for (int c; (c = getopt(argc, argv, "tui")) != -1;) {
            switch (c) {
                case 't': mode = total;
                    break;
                case 'u': mode = unique;
                    break;
                case 'i': mode = individual;
                    break;

            }
        }
        argc -= optind;
        argv += optind;
        string word;
        vector<string> list;
        vector<WordInfo> words;
        int count = 0;
        while (cin >> word) {

            switch(mode){
                case total : 
                    count += 1;
                    break;
                case unique :
                    if (find(list.begin(), list.end(), word) != list.end()){
                    } else {
                      count += 1; 
                    }
                    break;
                case individual :
                    if (find(list.begin(), list.end(), word) != list.end()) {
                        auto match = find(list.begin(), list.end(), word);
                        words.at(match - list.begin()).count++;
                    } else {
                        int count = 1;
                        WordInfo  tmp = (word, i);
                        words.push_back(tmp);
                    }
                    }    
        }


        switch (mode) {
            case total: cout << "Total " << count << endl;
                break;
            case unique: cout << "Unique " << count << endl;
                break;
            case individual: 
                for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++){
                    cout << words.at(i); << endl;
                }
                break;
        }

        return 0;
        }
```

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: `WordInfo  tmp = (word, i);` does not do what you think it does. Look up the comma operator.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you're using c++11?

`auto` has a completely different meaning to earlier compilers.

If you're using `g++`, try compiling with the `-std=c++11` flag:

```
g++ -std=c++11 foobar.cpp
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're using g++, set -std=c++11 to make use of auto to let the compiler figure out the type based on the expression.

however, you might also want to clean up your code - you shouldn't have to find once in the if statement and then again inside.

Answer (score 0):

Got some syntax error:

```
test.cpp:54:44: error: use of undeclared identifier 'i'
                WordInfo  tmp = (word, i);
                                       ^

test.cpp:68:31: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('ostream' (aka 

'basic_ostream<char>') and 'WordInfo')

                     cout << words.at(i); << endl;
                                        ^
```

See, you use undefined variable i and an extra ; in cout statement.